# MongoDB and Perl: maintaining insert order

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have been fooling with the Perl MongoDB library and have been hard pressed figuring out how to do something pretty simple.

How do I maintain the order of data fields upon an insert? My code is the following:

```
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::Database;
use MongoDB::OID;


my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new;
my $db = $conn->test;
my $users = $db->testlogwiki;


$users->insert
(
   {
     "product" => "WooHoo",
     "errcode" => "WM2001_89873",
     "solution1" => "Hit the computer.",
     "line_text" => "Inserted in Perl too"
   }
);
```

When I go back and look up in my MongoDB how the record has been inserted it looks like this:

db.testlogwiki.find([criteria that finds it]).pretty();

```
"_id" : ObjectId("4fc62c2900ece6040c000000"),
"solution1" : "Hit the computer.",
"product" : "WooHoo",
"errcode" : "WM2001_89873",
"line_text" : "Inserted in Perl too"
```

That's not the order I want...how do I make it the order I want?

Comment: Crosspost http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=973294

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Perl and Mongo's BSON hashes are unordered by definition. If you need to order properties in some way, you must keep track of it yourself.

Comment: Well damn. When I insert via the MongoDB shell ("mongo" app) it inserts in the same order that I put originally, so I spose the best thing to do would be to always insert from there. I wonder - is there a Perl library that operates THROUGH the Mongo shell. My guess is 99% no.

Comment: Please note "by definition". Right now shell happens to use JavaScript engine that keeps properties in the order you want, but it can change at any time without notice. You should never depend on undocumented behavior in your software. Just check amount of crying of people who tried to: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164.

Comment: Wow -- nice example from Oleg.

Comment: Hmmm you are right indeed. I'll code a workaround such that I don't need a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't necessarily have anything to do with this - Perl hashes don't preserve order in the first place:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'my $foo = { one => 1, two => 2, three => 3 }; print Dumper($foo);'
$VAR1 = {
          'three' => 3,
          'one' => 1,
          'two' => 2
        };
```

You can use [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aIxHash) to create hashes which will preserve their order in memory, but I can't say whether it would also make them preserve their order when inserted into and retrieved from MongoDB.